# missing json characters in REST service response - GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, guzzle

I'm using GuzzleHttp to comunicate with a local rest API. But in some cases the response is incomplete. is missing some last characters. the answer right in json format, and how missing some characters can not convert it. the strange thing is to test the API in the browser the response is complete.

```
<?php

class A {
    protected $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://localhost:8443/restcomponent/notes/',
            'timeout'  => 2.0,
            'verify' => false
        ]);

        $this->transformer = new RestNoteTransformer();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $httpMethod
     * @param string $path
     * @param array $options
     * @return mixed|\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected function request($httpMethod = 'GET', $path = '', array $options = [])
    {
        $options = array_merge($options, [
            'headers' => [
                'login.username' => 'admin',
                'login.password' => 'ofbiz',
            ]
        ]);

        return $this->client->request($httpMethod, $path, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Find user notes
     *
     * @param int $userId
     * @param int $page
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getNotesByUser($userId, $page = 1)
    {
        $response = $this->request('GET', '?page=' . $page . '&nReg=' . self::NUM_REGS . '&user=' . $userId);
        $contents = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $dto = json_decode($contents, false);

        var_dump($contents, $dto);
    }
}
```

**example of response:**

```
[{"noteTitle":"EDOM: Trabalho: Entrega 1","lastUpdatedStamp":1452462860644,"createdTxStamp":1452462860642,"createdStamp":1452462860644,"_ENTITY_NAME_":"Note","lastUpdatedTxStamp":1452462860642,"noteId":"10038","Latitude":"41.101273400000004","media":"","userId":"1","Longitude":"-8.6503474","noteType":"text","text":"sdfjkjhg\r\nhjkkkhjgchjlkçkhj\r\nhvnklçljgbhjkkhghjkhhjllkhghj","_DELEGATOR_NAME_":"default"},{"noteTitle":"EDOM: Trabalho: Entrega 1","lastUpdatedStamp":1452462985812,"createdTxStamp":1452462985809,"createdStamp":1452462985812,"_ENTITY_NAME_":"Note","lastUpdatedTxStamp":1452462985809,"noteId":"10039","Latitude":"41.101273400000004","media":"","userId":"1","Longitude":"-8.6503474","noteType":"text","text":"sdfjkjhg\r\nhjkkkhjgchjlkçkhj\r\nhvnklçljgbhjkkhghjkhhjllkhghj","_DELEGATOR_NAME_":"default"},{"noteTitle":"EDOM: Trabalho: Entrega 1","lastUpdatedStamp":1452462992254,"createdTxStamp":1452462992250,"createdStamp":1452462992254,"_ENTITY_NAME_":"Note","lastUpdatedTxStamp":1452462992250,"noteId":"10040","Latitude":"41.101273400000004","media":"","userId":"1","Longitude":"-8.6503474","noteType":"text","text":"sdfjkjhg\r\nhjkkkhjgchjlkçkhj\r\nhvnklçljgbhjkkhghjkhhjllkhghj","_DELEGATOR_NAME_":"default"},{"noteTitle":"EDOM: Trabalho: Entrega 1","lastUpdatedStamp":1452463164627,"createdTxStamp":1452463164626,"createdStamp":1452463164627,"_ENTITY_NAME_":"Note","lastUpdatedTxStamp":1452463164626,"noteId":"10046","Latitude":"41.101273400000004","media":"","userId":"1","Longitude":"-8.6503474","noteType":"text","text":"sdfjkjhg\r\nhjkkkhjgchjlkçkhj\r\nhvnklçljgbhjkkhghjkhhjllkhghj","_DELEGATOR_NAME_":"default"},{"noteTitle":"EDOM: Trabalho: Entrega 1","lastUpdatedStamp":1452463249756,"createdTxStamp":1452463249755,"createdStamp":1452463249756,"_ENTITY_NAME_":"Note","lastUpdatedTxStamp":1452463249755,"noteId":"10047","Latitude":"41.101273400000004","media":"","userId":"1","Longitude":"-8.6503474","noteType":"text","text":"sdfjkjhg\r\nhjkkkhjgchjlkçkhj\r\nhvnklçljgbhjkkhghjkhhjllkhghj","_DELEGATOR_NAME_":"default"},{"noteTitle":"EDOM: Trabalho: Entrega 1","lastUpdatedStamp":1452463284029,"createdTxStamp":1452463284027,"createdStamp":1452463284029,"_ENTITY_NAME_":"Note","lastUpdatedTxStamp":1452463284027,"noteId":"10048","Latitude":"41.101273400000004","media":"","userId":"1","Longitude":"-8.6503474","noteType":"text","text":"sdfjkjhg\r\nhjkkkhjgchjlkçkhj\r\nhvnklçljgbhjkkhghjkhhjllkhghj","_DELEGATOR_NAME_":"default"},{"noteTitle":"EDOM: Trabalho: Entrega 1","lastUpdatedStamp":1452463309824,"createdTxStamp":1452463309822,"createdStamp":1452463309824,"_ENTITY_NAME_":"Note","lastUpdatedTxStamp":1452463309822,"noteId":"10049","Latitude":"41.101273400000004","media":"","userId":"1","Longitude":"-8.6503474","noteType":"text","text":"sdfjkjhg\r\nhjkkkhjgchjlkçkhj\r\nhvnklçljgbhjkkhghjkhhjllkhghj","_DELEGATOR_NAME_":"default"},{"noteTitle":"Retrieve data from webservice","lastUpdatedStamp":1452463392692,"createdTxStamp":1452463392690,"createdStamp":1452463392692,"_ENTITY_NAME_":"Note","lastUpdatedTxStamp":1452463392690,"noteId":"10050","Latitude":"41.1012888","media":"","userId":"1","Longitude":"-8.6503467","noteType":"text","text":"kjhfcvghjkm\r\njnbhjmlmkh\r\nnhbhjkjhv","_DELEGATOR_NAME
```

Comment: Is it possible, that `timeout` of 2 seconds is too short?

Comment: unfortunately not, since changed it to 20